# Android - using sanselan to manually update pictures Exif data

Tags: android, android-camera, exif

Ive been trying to use the sanselan library for android to properly update my images rotation data but I cant get it to work. I was wondering if anybody on here has gotten this to work. Ive been on SO all day checking out answers to similar questions but nothing seemed to work yet. On both a galaxy s3 and motorola razor m I always get a landscape rotation embedded in the pic for some reason. Ive set the rotation property in the Parameters that I assign to my camera and everything but its still not working out. Does anyone have any idea, links, or examples on how they successfully manually updated the Exif data in an image in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some device, such as Galaxy S3, Note2 gives a rotated image. To get the image correctly
follow the steps belove:

1. Rotate the bitmap using the orientation exif info
2. Set the proper value to image exif orientation

If I see well, your problem comes out on step 2. If you try to update exif orientation, Sanselan will duplicate orientation attribute. So first of all, you have to remove the orientation values, and after add the value. I've worked out this way:

```
            List<?> sourceDirectories = outputSet.getDirectories();
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceDirectories.size(); i++) {
                TiffOutputDirectory sourceDirectory = (TiffOutputDirectory) sourceDirectories.get(i);

                List<?> sourceFields = sourceDirectory.getFields();
                for (int j = 0; j < sourceFields.size(); j++) {
                    TiffOutputField sourceField = (TiffOutputField) sourceFields.get(j);
                    if (sourceField.tagInfo.name.equals("Orientation")) {
                        sourceDirectory.removeField(sourceField.tagInfo);
                    }
                }
            }

            TiffOutputDirectory tiffDirectory = outputSet.getExifDirectory();
            TiffOutputField orientationField = TiffOutputField.create(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_ORIENTATION, outputSet.byteOrder, 1);
            tiffDirectory.add(orientationField);
```

[This article could help you in orientation value](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)

Comment: I ended up using something like this but still on certain odd ball devices you cant read exif data from pictures taken with the devices hardware. In that case I just let the images do their own thing and everything works